# libssh2, check if a session still active or if is disconnected

Tags: objective-c, libssh2

I am using the libssh2 lib and I want to know if there is any way to know if a session still active or if is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that a session only becomes active after a handshake has been performed, this sets up the transport layer for the associated socket.

As far as I know, I don't think there is a particular function to test if a session is still active.  You would have to see if the socket attached to the session is still active.